# SVGs not showing in Windows Phone 8 Phonegap app

Tags: html, windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, svg

Can't seem to find any answers on this.

Developing an HTML5 app with Phonegap and using SVG images. Saving them from Adobe Illustrator's "Save as.." and then using them like normal images in the HTML:

```
<img src="img/the_image.svg" />
```

They show up fine in Android and iPhone but Windows Phone 8 shows them as broken links. Anything I'm doing wrong? Does WP8 not support SVGs this way?

Comment: Try `<object data="img/the_image.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>`.

Answer (score 10):

remove the starting XML tag from the SVG image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: this is both unbelievable and gross, and true. did not seem to have any sideeffects on android and iphone. it also accounts for svg used as background-image in css.