# cordova phonegap wp8 svg broken in image tag

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8, svg

I am programming a wp8 app and use svg's in image tags like so

```
<img src="images/logo.svg" />
```

When I open it in the browser of my windows phone everything looks fine, but when I run it as an app the images show up as broken links.

The weird thing is that a remote svg like this works fine as well (also with the exact same file)

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg" />
```

Has somebody had this problem as well? PNG for example works locally and remotly.

Comment: Just remove the xml start tag from the SVG image.

Comment: awesome thx! it works! if you put it as answer i can mark it as solved

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVGs not showing in Windows Phone 8 Phonegap app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526492/svgs-not-showing-in-windows-phone-8-phonegap-app)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove the xml start tag from the SVG image