# Some SVGs not displaying in Windows Phone 8.1 (PhoneGap)

Tags: html, cordova, svg, windows-phone-8.1, adobe-illustrator

Firstly, I know about the problem with the starting XML tag my question  [not about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526492/svgs-not-showing-in-windows-phone-8-phonegap-app).

I have a many multi-layered .ai files (Adobe Illustrator CC 2015 19v)
Each layer it is a copy previous layer + some changes. ([something similar to this](http://www.dragoart.com/tuts/23164/1/1/how-to-draw-kylo-ren-easy.htm))

- If I save top layer it is perfectly displayed on all devices.
  (desktop, android, WP8.1)
- If I save lower layers it is do not displayed in WP 8.1.

I tried different options are saved, but nothing has changed. This occurs with each .ai file.

Then I decided to explore the text representation of the svg files. If I copy the style from top layer at the nontop, then everything is OK. They are displayed.

**Start SVG file TOP LAYER (7/7)** - (***displayed***)

```
<svg id="lesson_2_7" data-name="lesson 2 7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 686 526"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;}.cls-2{fill:#a2a2a2;}.cls-3{fill:#6c6c6c;}.cls-4{fill:#a9aeb7;}.cls-5{fill:#6f6f6f;}.cls-6{mask:url(#mask);}.cls-7{fill:#adadad;}.cls-8{mask:url(#mask-2);}.cls-9{fill:#46cc00;}.cls-10{fill:#fff7f7;}.cls-11{filter:url(#luminosity-noclip-2);}.cls-12{filter:url(#luminosity-noclip);}</style>
```

**Start SVG file NONTOP LAYER (5/7)** - (***not displayed***)

```
<svg id="lesson_2_5" data-name="lesson 2 5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 686 526"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;}.cls-2{fill:#fff7f7;}</style>
```

**Start SVG file NONTOP LAYER with Style from TOP (5/7)** - (***displayed***)

```
<svg id="lesson_2_5" data-name="lesson 2 5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 686 526"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;}.cls-2{fill:#a2a2a2;}.cls-3{fill:#6c6c6c;}.cls-4{fill:#a9aeb7;}.cls-5{fill:#6f6f6f;}.cls-6{mask:url(#mask);}.cls-7{fill:#adadad;}.cls-8{mask:url(#mask-2);}.cls-9{fill:#46cc00;}.cls-10{fill:#fff7f7;}.cls-11{filter:url(#luminosity-noclip-2);}.cls-12{filter:url(#luminosity-noclip);}</style>
```

As if not enough styles to display the image. 
[image]

[I downloaded the entire SVG for example here.](http://gist.github.com/KVinS/7a6a7d576d8cc47b094d)

Someone met similar? I'll be glad to any idea. Perhaps, as need to configure AI for export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE in PhoneGap doesn't not render SVG with < 7 styles.